# pattern matching for tuple in erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm a new learner of erlang, and i'm looking for a book called `Introducing erlang`. In the book, it has some examples as below:

```
-module(ask).
-export([term/0]).

term() ->
    Input = io:read("What {planemo, distance} ? >>"),
    process_term(Input).

process_term({ok, Term}) when is_tuple(Term) ->
    Velocity = drop:fall_velocity(Term),
    io:format("Yields ~w. ~n",[Velocity]),
    term();

process_term({ok, quit}) ->
    io:format("Goodbye.~n");
    % does not call term() again

process_term({ok, _}) ->
    io:format("You must enter a tuple.~n"),
    term();

process_term({error, _}) ->
    io:format("You must enter a tuple with correct syntax.~n"),
    term().
```

Below is the examples which call the `ask` module:

```
6> c(ask).
{ok,ask}
7> ask:term().
What {planet, distance} ? >>{mars,20}.
Yields 12.181953866272849.
What {planet, distance} ? >>20.
You must enter a tuple.
What {planet, distance} ? >>quit.
Goodbye.
ok
```

I don't understand why `What {planet, distance} ? >>quit.` matches the `process_term({ok, quit})` function? you entered only `'quit'`, not a tuple,
I think it should not match  `process_term({ok, quit})` function. Could anybody out there explain why?

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation of `io:read/1` (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#read-1) it returns a tuple `{ok, Term}`. Ie you type *foo*, `io:read` returns `{ok, foo}`, you type `{bar, 10}`, `io:read` returns `{ok, {bar, 10}}`.

All the `process_term` clauses match on `{ok, _whatever the user typed_}`, or if something failed, `{error, Reason}` (which is all Erlang style).

Answer (score 0):

Also, In your code, you have `process_term({ok, Term}) when is_tuple(Term) ->` which takes the input, provided it is a tuple, hence the `when` clause. When you enter 'quit', it does not have to be a tuple to be accepted by the `{ok, quit}`, it pattern matches them and returns the ouput. 
Hope this helps.